# MultiLabelBinarizer output classes in letters instead of categories

Tags: python, multilabel-classification

I have a dataframe where one column is `short_names`. `short_names` consist of 2-5 letters of names => `BG`,`OP`,`LE`,`WEL`,`LC`. Each row can have any number of names.

I am trying to use `MultiLabelBinarizer` to convert the names into individual columns such that if the rows have similar names then there will be 1 in the columns

```
one_hot = MultiLabelBinarizer()
one_hot.fit_transform(df['short_name']) 
one_hot.classes__
```

Because there is a '-' in one the rows which result in an error `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`, I have used

```
df['short_names']= df['short_names'].astype(str)
```

The issue now is that the classes output is letters instead of the short names i.e. `A`, `B`, `C` instead of `BG` `OP`

Comment: What is `print (df['short_name'].head().to_dict())` ?

Comment: {0: nan, 1: 'CE', 2: 'NPP', 4: 'SE, CB, CBN, OOM, BCI', 5: 'RCS'}

Comment: What is expected output? remove rows with problematic values?

Comment: array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1,1,1,0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,01],           if there are common labels in other rows, it should point to 1 in the same columns
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think need [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dropna.html) for remove [missing values](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html) with [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) if necessary:

```
df = pd.Series({0: np.nan, 1: 'CE', 2: 'NPP', 4: 'SE, CB, CBN, OOM, BCI', 5: 'RCS'})
       .to_frame('short_name')
print (df)
              short_name
0                    NaN
1                     CE
2                    NPP
4  SE, CB, CBN, OOM, BCI
5                    RCS

from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
one_hot = MultiLabelBinarizer()
a = one_hot.fit_transform(df['short_name'].dropna().str.split(', ')) 
print (a)
[[0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]]

print(one_hot.classes_ )
['BCI' 'CB' 'CBN' 'CE' 'NPP' 'OOM' 'RCS' 'SE']
```

If want output `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=one_hot.classes_ )
print (df)
   BCI  CB  CBN  CE  NPP  OOM  RCS  SE
0    0   0    0   1    0    0    0   0
1    0   0    0   0    1    0    0   0
2    1   1    1   0    0    1    0   1
3    0   0    0   0    0    0    1   0
```

---

Another solution is replace `missing values` by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
one_hot = MultiLabelBinarizer()
a = one_hot.fit_transform(df['short_name'].fillna('missing').str.split(', ')) 
print (a)
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]]

print(one_hot.classes_ )
['BCI' 'CB' 'CBN' 'CE' 'NPP' 'OOM' 'RCS' 'SE' 'missing']

df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=one_hot.classes_ )
print (df)
   BCI  CB  CBN  CE  NPP  OOM  RCS  SE  missing
0    0   0    0   0    0    0    0   0        1
1    0   0    0   1    0    0    0   0        0
2    0   0    0   0    1    0    0   0        0
3    1   1    1   0    0    1    0   1        0
4    0   0    0   0    0    0    1   0        0
```

Comment: It works ! thank you . what is the cause of the errors ?

Comment: why was it outputing letters instead of the short names ?

Comment: if i would like to combine the columns together, how should i do so ? let's say i want to combine the '1' in CE and CBN together into a new column

Comment: @Lko - If think `a = one_hot.fit_transform(df['short_name'].astype(str))`there is problem need lists, not strings. If strings then each value is pocesses separately

Comment: @jezrael so should I fit `one_hot` only on **(training set and only transform testing set)** or **fit it on (training and testing set) both**.

Comment: @10sha25 - I am ashamed a lot, but honestly no idea :(