# How to use MultiLabelBinarizer for Multilabel classification?

Tags: pandas, multilabel-classification, data-preprocessing

I am trying to do multilabel classification. But I am really stuck at data preprocessing. My target data in in a separate file. The target data looks like this

```
   Id              Tag
0   1             data
1   4               c#
2   4         winforms
3   4  type-conversion
4   4          decimal
```

I am trying to use MultiLabelBinarizer to preprocess the data. At the end of it, I want it to look something like this -

| ID | data | c# | winforms | type-conversion | decimal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

This is the code that I am using

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

question_tags = pd.read_csv("./archive/question_tags.csv")
print(question_tags.head())
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
print(mlb.fit_transform(question_tags))
```

This is the output I am getting.

```
[[1 0 0 1 0]
 [0 1 1 0 1]]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51335634/6660373

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything wrong. `MultiLabelBinarizer()`, as most other `sklearn` stuff, returns numpy arrays. In this case, the underlying data looks identical to your expected output, sans the `ID` and `Tag` names.

Use `pd.crosstab` instead:

```
pd.crosstab(df['Id'], df['Tag'])
```

Comment: I guess this won't help as you will have prediction dataset also. This involves machine Learning. your test data may not have the same tag(might have some missing tags) then there will be an issue of  mismatch column.

Comment: @Pygirl There's `reindex` for that. And also, it's a horrible idea to have test set so different from the dev set.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this out. That means we can do this via pandas also without having data leakage problem. But that's only for category column. right?